# Preventing push-spring drain stoppers from getting stuck

Tags: drain, sink

I have dealt with several sink drains that have a spring-loaded stopper like the one shown here.  It is designed to be pushed down to stop the drain, and pushed again to pop up and unstop the drain.  The problem is that **when it is not frequently used it will tend to get stuck in the stopped position**.  This occurs even when no debris is encumbering the mechanism.

The only way I have found of fixing these when they get stuck that way is to unscrew them from the drain and begin to jimmy or disassemble them until the spring returns the stopper into the unstopped condition.  At that point I toggle it a few times until it does so reliably and without sticking, and then return it to service.  But if it is not frequently used it will invariably get stuck again.

Are there any means of reliably preventing these from getting stuck in the stopped position?

[image: Push spring sink drain stopper]

Answer (score 1):

Next time you have to disassemble it, clean it real good with some emery paper and then rub some plumber's grease over the parts and reassemble. Don't use regular silicone grease, get the plumber's silicone grease. It's thicker and lasts much longer. Good luck.